# Fastest way to reverse a string in C

Tags: c

Is this function the fastest, most optimized way of reversing a string in C? This runs in O(n/2) time. The optimization is that it only iterates through half of the string.

```
char* str_reverse(char *str, int len)
{
    char word[len];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= len / 2; ++i) {
        word[i] = str[len - i - 1];
        word[len - i - 1] = str[i];
    }
    word[len] = '\0';
    return word;
}
```

Comment: fastest solution? build a huge hash map for all strings and its reverse value, you have O(1) computation time, and O(some huge constant) memory footprint (assuming inputs are finite)

Comment: You should say `n/2` operations, not `O(n/2)`. `O(n/2)` is the same as `O(n)`, as the constants don't count in asymptotic notation. The algorithm is fastest with `O(1)` space. If you have unbounded memory, then see @Bryan Chen's comment.

Comment: You cannot return pointer-to-`word` as it is a local variable. That leads to undefined behaviour. If you do not need to keep `str` intact you could reverse in place else you need to `malloc` memory before.

Comment: Bitwise in-place string reversal might be faster and more efficient, depending on instruction sets, compilers, etc.?  I'm pretty sure it's more efficient for strings that are too long to fit in a page of memory because of locality.

Comment: Make it work before you make it fast should be your first priority. After that you profile to make sure that the time you invest making it fast is really needed. The bottleneck might be somewhere else.

Comment: it may run in n/2 iterations, but each iteration uses 2x the array-access operations as the similar approach running in n iterations, so the total count of operations is a wash.  the previous comments are all very good, as well.

Comment: @BryanChen That would have O(n) time to compute the hash of the input string. You can't avoid O(n) because you have to process every character in the string.

Comment: not the fastest, here's a simple improvement by having less comparison:     for (i = 0; i <= len / 2; i += 2) {
        word[i] = str[len - i - 1]; word[len - i - 1] = str[i]; word[i+1]=str[len-i-2];word[len-i-2]=str[i+1];
    }  followed by:     for (; i <= len / 2; ++i) {
        word[i] = str[len - i - 1];
        word[len - i - 1] = str[i];
    }

Comment: @DUJiaen What if your string has length 1? Then you have an out of bound access.

Comment: @RedX, yeah there's a bug, should be i<len/2 in the initial loop

Comment: Does the output string have to be a standard C-style null-terminated one? If not, you can simply say "my strings are stored in right-to-left character order", and be done with it - no actual data fiddling necessary.

Comment: When `len` is odd, the code unnecessarily copies the middle element twice. When `len` is even it's worse, copying the middle *two* elements twice. But the [suggested change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34035169/fastest-way-to-reverse-a-string-in-c#comment55826134_34035169) of `i<=len/2` to `i<len/2` doesn't fix it: the middle element of an odd-length string won't be copied at all.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
char *str_reverse_in_place(char *str, int len)
{
    char *p1 = str;
    char *p2 = str + len - 1;

    while (p1 < p2) {
        char tmp = *p1;
        *p1++ = *p2;
        *p2-- = tmp;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Comment: I would say this one wins ;)

Comment: It's so streamlined I can almost imagine the assembly instructions while looking at it ;)

Comment: This is nowhere even CLOSE to being the fastest implementation of string reversing.  Someone has already given a much better example below.  Firstly perform the swap using 4 bytes at a time using the bswap instruction or its intrinsic, do NOT reverse things byte-wise.  The only hit you take with bswap is alignment, because the end of your string may not be aligned optimally.  The start of your string usually will be though and you can get around alignment issues by trimming.  This method is seriously more efficient than the above code.

Comment: could we see test runs of length wrt time comparison? :) table/plot

Comment: Why `char tmp` is not defined outside the `while`-loop and then just `tmp = *p1;` ?

Comment: Ummm, makes a lot of sense @keithmo, it is way faster for the processor to compare char vs char instead of string vs string IO and O^2 is way higher

Answer (score 5):

You'll find algorithms taking less instructions, like this *in place* reverse

```
char* str_reverse_in_place(char *str, int len)
{
    int i;
    for (i = len/2-1 ; i >= 0 ; --i) {
        char c = str[i];
        str[i] = str[len-i-1];
        str[len-i-1] = c;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Optimizing for speed at that level, look at the *inline* keyword, also compile with (for gcc) with `-O3` (does usually a better job that adding *register* ... by yourself).

If you need to have the reversed string elsewhere, either provide it in the function (being allocated for `strlen(str)+1` - actually `len+1` here - characters)

```
char* str_reverse(char *str, char *reverse, int len)
{
    int i;
    for (i = len-1 ; i >= 0 ; --i) {
        reverse[i] = str[len-i-1];
    }
    reverse[len] = 0;
    return reverse;
}
```

or *malloc* it (it will have to be freed by the caller).

```
char* str_reverse_malloc(char *str, int len)
{
    char *reverse = malloc(len+1);
    if ( ! reverse) return NULL;
    int i;
    for (i = len-1 ; i >= 0 ; --i) {
        reverse[i] = str[len-i-1];
    }
    reverse[len] = 0;
    return reverse;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The "most" optimized way must address the question of CPU and memory architecture as well as what is being reversed (long strings or short strings and what is the distribution).

There's no way to get relax the O(N) requirement, but one can use techniques such as loop unrolling, loop blocking and parallelism to optimize cache misses for very large strings. Also one can increase the word size and swap words, dwords or larger entities in-place (while dealing with the probable alignment issue).

// This will most likely be faster than byte-wise copying, but it's not O(N/8)...

```
if (len & 7 == 0)
{
    uint32_t *dst = src+len-4;
    uint32_t *src = (uint32_t *)ptr;
    while (src<dst)
    {
      a = *src; b = *dst;
      *src++ = byte_swap(b);
      *dst-- = byte_swap(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `byte_swap`? and where is that defined?

Comment: not OP, but bswap is a x86 instruction that inverts the bytes of a 32 bit or 64 bit word

Answer (score 3):

```
int main() {
   char str[100], temp;
   int i, j = 0;
 
   printf("\nEnter the string :");
   fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
 
   i = 0;
   j = strlen(str) - 1;
 
   while (i < j) {
      temp = str[i];
      str[i] = str[j];
      str[j] = temp;
      i++;
      j--;
   }
 
   printf("\nReverse string is :%s", str);
   return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, when considering complexity, it's impossible to do better than O(n) where n is the length of the string. Every single element - except for one element in the middle when n is odd - needs to be moved, and there is no way around it.

Also, this problem is so simple, so it's barely impossible to do something dramatic if you only consider the pure algorithm and not take real life factors into account. For very large strings, the single most important thing will be if the algorithm is cache friendly or not.

Here is a version which is cache friendly. It's not an in-place variant. If modified to in place, it can become even more cache friendly. First, we need a simple reverse function which does NOT terminate the destination string:

```
void str_reverse_aux(char *dest, const char *src, int len) {
    for (int i = len-1 ; i >= 0 ; --i) 
        dest[i] = src[len-i-1];
}
```

After that, we use an algorithm that takes the N first and N last characters of a string, reverse both and swap their positions. Then move N step inwards from both directions and repeat until there is less than 2*N characters to process. Then we call the above function to finish things of.

```
void str_reverse(char *dest, const char *src, int block_size) {
    int len = strlen(src);
    
    char *d       = dest;
    const char *s = src;
    
    int chunks = len / (2 * block_size);
    
    char *dtail = &dest[len];
    char *stail = &src [len];
    
    for(int i=0; i<chunks; i++) { // Reverse the string blockwise
        dtail -= block_size;
        stail -= block_size;
        
        char *buf = alloca(block_size); // Almost equivalent to char buf[block_size];
        
        str_reverse_aux(buf, s, block_size);
        memcpy(d, buf, block_size);

        str_reverse_aux(buf, stail, block_size);
        memcpy(dtail, buf, block_size);
        
        d+=block_size;
        s+=block_size;
    }

    str_reverse_aux(d, s, len - 2* chunks * block_size); // Take care of remainder
    dest[len] = 0;
}
```

For very large strings, this will give a huge performance boost.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation that does not require the length to be passed and will swap both the beginning and ending characters at a given offset within the string each pass through the loop:

```
/** strrevstr - reverse string, swaps src & dest each iteration.
 *  Takes valid string and reverses, original is not preserved.
 *  If str is valid, returns pointer to str, NULL otherwise.
 */
char *strrevstr (char *str)
{
    if (!str) {
        printf ("strrevstr() error: invalid string\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    char *begin = str;
    char *end = str + strlen (str) - 1;
    char tmp;

    while (end > begin)
    {
        tmp = *end;
        *end-- = *begin;
        *begin++ = tmp;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one just for fun. But I reckon it's as fast as some of the others posted here.
The fun part is in the bitwise xor! Do that on paper, it works!

```
void inplace_swap(char *x, char *y) {
    *y = *x ^ *y;
    *x = *x ^ *y;
    *y = *x ^ *y;
}

void reverse_string(char *str, int len) {
    int first, last;
    for (first = 0, last = len - 1; first < last; first++, last--) {
        inplace_swap(&str[first], &str[last]);
    }
}
```

Comment: In practice, this is usually slower

Answer (score -1):

This is faster than fastest way to reverse string in C ... ;)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    char string[] = "hello";
    int len = strlen(string);
    char reverse[len];
    
 
    for (int i = 0; i<len; i++){
        reverse[i] = string[len - i - 1];
      }

     printf("%s",reverse);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for answering but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the issue? Also check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.