# Is there a more efficient way to reverse decimal numbers?

Tags: c, decimal, reverse

I am trying to reverse decimal numbers more efficient.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

while(1)
 {
 int a,result;
  
 scanf("%d",&a);
  
 result=(a%10*10)+(a/10);

 printf("%d\n",result);

 }
}
```

Of course this will only work with 2 decimal numbers.

But I am trying to find out how I can reverse more numbers in an efficient way ( less code)

Comment: How do you mean "more efficient"?  Less code for you?  Faster runtime?

Comment: Sorry I need to be more specific. LESS CODE

Comment: Less code: read as a string instead of integer. If you are interested in its digits, that means you need it in a decimal, not binary, format. If you have it as integer (binary format) you have to unpick it. `scanf("%d",&a);` is reading characters from a file or keyboard and converting them to an integer. If you use `scanf("%s", str);` there you have the digits that were typed.

Comment: Some exemples are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34035169/fastest-way-to-reverse-a-string-in-c However, minimising the size of code (codegolf challenge?) was not the main goal. But codes there are rather short

Comment: So the reverse of 10 would be 1? But the reverse of 1 is also 1.

Comment: In a codegolf spirit, you can try this: `out = 0; while (out=10*out+in%10, in/=10);`But looking for minimizing the number of lines of code is generally not a good idea.

Comment: Jossver Kraan  If input was `"0123"`, what output expected? `"3210", "321", something , else?

Comment: @JossverKraan If the  reversed value exceeds `long` range, what should code do?

Comment: Make a lookup array `int inv[100] = {0, 10, 20, ..., 90, 1, 11, 21, ... 99}; /* not code */` and then your single line of code: `result = inv[a];`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long in = 3456789;
    long out = 0;
    while(in)
    {
        out *= 10;
        out += in % 10;
        in /= 10;
    }
    printf("%ld\n",out);
    return 0;
}
```

This way it will work for every type of number, no matter the number of digits, as long as it matches the data type.

Comment: `printf("%d\n", in);` ==> `printf("%ld\n", out);`

Comment: "it will work for every type of number" --> fails when `out *= 10` overflows.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oopsie, sorry for the mistake

Comment: I will be more careful from now on

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry I need to be more specific. LESS CODE –

Ugly, but short code to "reverse" a number.

```
int main(){int c=getchar();if(isdigit(c))main();putchar(c);}
```

Comment: So the isdigit function checks if the input is a numerical character? does this means it reverse the character one by one ( sorry if I do not fully understand this)

Comment: @JossverKraan "sorry if I do not fully understand this" is the problem with requesting "less code".  It is not so easy to understand, lacking clear structure, names, idioms.  Above code does a recursive call on `main()` to achieve input stacked up and then printed in reverse order.   IMO, best to request clear code even if it is not less code.  IAC, consider responding to questions in the comment section under your post.