# In C, given char *ptr and defined till ptr+n, when I tried statements similar to (ptr+i) = (ptr+j); where i,j<n, I got "lvalue error". Why?

Tags: c, pointers, reverse, c-strings, function-definition

While compiling this below given code, I got the **error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment** for both the statements `str+i = str+((len-1)-i);` and `str+((len-1)-i) = temp;`.

Why?

```
char* str_reverse(char *str, int len)
{
    char *temp;
    int i, mid;

    if(len%2 == 0)
    {
        mid = len/2 - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        mid = (len-1)/2;
    }

    for(i=0;i<mid;i++)
    {
        temp = str+i;
        str+i = str+((len-1)-i);
        str+((len-1)-i) = temp;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Comment: Because `str+i` is not an lvalue (see for example [What is an lvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397745/what-is-an-lvalue)). The statement doesn't swap characters as you intend it to. Should be `*(str+i)=*(str+((len-1)-i))`. Or more simply `str[i] = str[len-1-i]`. Same for all the other assignments

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this: I wanted to assign the address of ```(str+((len-1)-i))``` to ```str+i``` , not the value stored in it.

Comment: Why? That makes no sense. That will not swap the characters at all.

Comment: I wanted to reverse the order of characters stored in pointer ```str```. So, I thought to **re-allocate their memory addresses** in such a way that:

calling ```str[0]``` would would return the value of ```str[(n-1)-0]```.
calling ```str[1]``` would would return the value of ```str[(n-1)-1]```.
calling ```str[2]``` would would return the value of ```str[(n-1)-2]```.
.
.
.
and so on. (I don't know whether this method works, I'm new to programming, hence I don't know much of its rules.)

I wanted to know that, if this statement doesn't serve my purpose, Why?

Comment: @Algorithmophile You can't individually reallocate the addresses of the elements of an array.  It's the definition of an array that its elements are all stored in contiguous memory.  So the address of every element of an array is always at a fixed offset from the base address, that is, the beginning of the array.  If you want to rearrange the elements of an array, rearranging the values is your only choice.

Comment: Even if you *could* rearrange the addresses of the individual elements of an array, moving 4- or 8-buyte addresses around, to avoid the overhead of moving single characters around, would probably not be a good tradeoff! :-)

Comment: Okay. I thought re-allocating addresses (if it is possible) would be faster than re-allocating the values. I was trying this bounty question https://stackoverflow.com/q/34035169/15933960 . So, I thought about this method. Thank you all for support :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expressions like this

```
str + i
```

are rvalues. They can not be assigned. It is the same as to write

```
int x = 10;
int y = 20;

x + y = 30;
```

But in any case your function is in essence incorrect. You need to swap characters instead of trying to swap pointer expressions.

Also this if statement

```
if(len%2 == 0)
{
    mid = len/2 - 1;
}
else
{
    mid = (len-1)/2;
}
```

does not make a great sense because the result of the expression

```
len / 2
```

is the same whether `len` is an even number or the following odd number.

For example `2 / 2` is equal to `1` and `3 / 2` is also equal to `1`.

Using pointers within the function it can be defined the following way

```
char * str_reverse( char *str, size_t len )
{
    if ( len != 0 )
    {
        for ( char *left = str, *right = str + len; left < --right; ++left )
        {
            char c = *left;
            *left = *right;
            *right = c;
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`str` is an lvalue because it is a place in memory which contains an address.

`str+i`  is only an rvalue because it is only an address

Answer (score 0):

Use size_t for string lengths.

You are overcomplicating this:

```
char* str_reverse(char *str, size_t len)
{
    char temp, *start = str, *end = str + len -1;
    if(str && *str)
    {
        while(start < end)
        {
            temp = *start;
            *start++ = *end;
            *end-- = temp;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```